# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ST_SIZEGRIP'

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having a problem trying to run a software called pyPENELOPE. After install it perfectly, i've tried run the software and received the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pypenelope", line 6, in <module>
    from penelopetools.gui.main import run
  File "/usr/share/python-penelope/penelopetools/gui/main.py", line 52, in <module>
    from wxtools.statusbar import EnhancedStatusBar
  File "/usr/share/python-penelope/wxtools/statusbar.py", line 72, in <module>
    class EnhancedStatusBar(wx.StatusBar):
  File "/usr/share/python-penelope/wxtools/statusbar.py", line 74, in EnhancedStatusBar
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.ST_SIZEGRIP,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ST_SIZEGRIP'
```

Searching, I found that the problem might be in this call in the code

```
import wx
```

and I need to put the lines

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select('2.8')
import wx
```

But then i've receive de the message

```
    wxversion.select('2.8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wxversion.py", line 144, in select
    raise AlreadyImportedError("wxversion.select() must be called before wxPython is imported")
wxversion.AlreadyImportedError: wxversion.select() must be called before wxPython is imported
```

Calling `wxversion.select('2.8')` before the `import wxversion` i've received

```
  File "/usr/share/python-penelope/wxtools/statusbar.py", line 48, in <module>
    wxversion.select('2.8')
NameError: name 'wxversion' is not defined
```

So.... What can I do?

Comment: Try installing wxPython version 2.8 and then you shouldn't have to worry about `wxversion`. That said, look for another tool, as pypenelope doesn't appear to have been updated since 2012.

Comment: that's the first thing I tried =/

Comment: It seems you have the source ` File "/usr/share/python-penelope/wxtools/statusbar.py"` so you have the option of changing it but it doesn't augur well.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you are using python3 for pyPENELOPE, you can remove the wxversion lines and instead change ST_SIZEGRIP to STB_SIZEGRIP and your code should compile.

Best of luck,
Bunny.

Comment: This worked for me 2022_04_12